# Wireless interface not working in VirtualBox Kali guest

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, airmon-ng

I have installed Kali Linux as a guest OS in VirtualBox. I have enabled the bridge adapter and wireless interface wlan1 to the VirtualBox, but I am unable to see the wlan interface in the Kali Linux. For that I searched in Google. I found [this file](http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2010-12-25.tar.bz2)

```
$ uname -a
Linux kali 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.18.6-1~kali2 (2015-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@kali:~/Downloads/compat-wireless-2010-12-25# make load
/bin/sh: 1: [: -gt: argument expected
/bin/sh: 1: test: -ge: unexpected operator
make: *** No rule to make target `load'.  Stop.
root@kali:~/Downloads/compat-wireless-2010-12-25# make unload
/bin/sh: 1: [: -gt: argument expected
/bin/sh: 1: test: -ge: unexpected operator
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
Stoping bluetooth service..
[ ok ] Stopping bluetooth: rfcomm /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
[FAIL] bluetooth is not running ... failed!
Unloading rfcomm...

root@kali:~/Downloads/compat-wireless-2010-12-25# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

]

How can I solve this?

[image]

But my guest Kali Linux is working like NAT its having eth0 interface and getting the Internet as well. But I need to have wlan0 interface in VirtualBox guest Kali Linux to use aircrack-ng, airmon-ng, etc.

Answer (score 1):

your Kali Linux system is running as a virtual machine not a physical machine and you have attached wifi hardware on host machine not to geust machine . so , you will not be able to direct access of wifi in guest machine.

> solution : connect to wifi on host system and then you have to create
>   bridged or Nat to guest system to connect internet.

Comment: i had connected already see the configuration.

Comment: is your internet not working in guest machine ?

Comment: no its working see the edited question

Comment: i think you are doing something wrong if internet is not comming on guest machine by bridged or nat . if you are looking for wlan1 on guest machine then it will not show . your are not accessing wifi you are using Ethernet port to connect Internet on guest machine

Comment: Then how i could use the tools like airmon-ng and aircrack-ng

Comment: i am getting the internet

Comment: it is connecting to the internet(wifi) through eth0 but i need to go using wlan

Comment: you have to install kali as host os . if you have important data and daily user of current host machine then you can make it dual boot. by changing of port name it will not become wlan it will remain ethernet internet .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26824/discussion-between-ashok-and-prameswar-lal).

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative solution:

I used to connect a wifi to the USB (since a certain wifi chip type is needed to support promiscuous mode when using `aircrack-ng`) and attach that USB device (the wifi device) to the VM so it is able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The file linked in the question is a set of old wireless drivers from year 2010 for Linux kernel versions 2.6.xx. It is hopelessly out of date and likely incompatible with modern Kali Linux. It will not solve your problem.

Even the "Bridged Adapter" mode of VirtualBox presents the WiFi adapter to the virtual machine as a generic wired LAN interface. Tools like `aircrack-ng` and `airmon-ng` require access to WiFi-specific "monitor mode", which does not exist on LAN interfaces, and not provided by VirtualBox at all.

If you have an USB-based WiFi adapter, you could use the Settings... -> USB page to give your Kali VM an exclusive access to the USB WiFi adapter. You'll need to add a new USB Filter that matches your USB WiFi adapter, then make sure the filter is activated at the USB settings page so it will automatically enable as soon as the Kali VM is started.

If your WiFi adapter is PCI- or PCIe-based, it *might* be possible to use [the PCI Passthrough feature of VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) to give the VM exclusive access to the WiFi adapter. Note that PCI Passthrough is an advanced feature that has several extra system requirements. **I have not tested this, and so cannot provide further advice, but I've heard some people have succeeded with it.**

Both exclusive access methods mean that the WiFi adapter will become unusable in the host OS while you run the VM that is configured to take full control of the WiFi hardware. This also means you should not configure the WiFi adapter at all in the VM's Settings... -> Network page; instead, once you've configured VirtualBox to turn over full WiFi adapter access to the VM, you should configure the WiFi adapter in the Kali VM just like a real physical adapter in an actual physical Kali Linux system.